# Starting activity(android app development)

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start an activity from my mainActivity.
Here's my mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello world", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Intent.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And here's my Intent class which I want to start:

```
public class Intent extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intent1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

but the program crashes in runtime. why?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give the stack trace of the crash, and we might be able to assist you in debugging it.

Comment: Just change your class name from `Intent` to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have named the activity that you want to start as Intent and you are also initializing an Intent object from the Android core package. Of course, there will be a namespace collision as only one of these classes is actually imported and you will not get desired behavior.